# 2D Side Scrolling HTML5 Game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, side-scroller

I am trying to make a side scrolling game in html5. I am wondering how i can have lets say a 500px by 500px viewing are but the background is about 500px high by 2000px wide. When the viewing area scrolls more of the background appears but the character stays in the middle similar to how the pokemon games are.

Comment: In the future, it is helpful to show what you've already tried or at least what you've considered. Additionally, you might consider asking your question more directly, e.g., "How can I create a 500px by 500px viewing area where the background is 500px by 2000px?"

Answer (score 2):

The `context.drawImage` function has a whole bunch of arguments you can give it. You want to play with the source (image) `x, y, width, height` and destination (screen) `x, y, width, height`. Here is the argument list for `drawImage`.

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
```

So the following will draw the image starting `400px` from the left to `900px` from the left.

```
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var scrollPos = 400;
drawImage(image, scrollPos, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
```

**Further reading**

- [WebPlatform drawImage](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)